# ELastic Search || 7.9.3 || java.io.IOException: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: elasticsearch

recently we are facing very strange behavior on our Elastic search cluster as cluster status change from green status to red status and after check we found some shards are unassigned  and after check data node logs we found the following exception although we have enough memory on the server

Exception:

````
java.io.IOException: Cannot allocate memory
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.force0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.force(FileDispatcherImpl.java:82) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.force(FileChannelImpl.java:465) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.TranslogWriter.syncUpTo(TranslogWriter.java:376) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog.ensureSynced(Translog.java:784) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog.ensureSynced(Translog.java:805) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.ensureTranslogSynced(InternalEngine.java:535) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard$5.write(IndexShard.java:3090) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]```
````

Comment: Do you monitor heap usage on the node? Do you have heap size set to ~50% of total available RAM?

Comment: you need to share a bunch more info to allow us to help here. what is the output from the `_cluster/stats?pretty&human` API? what does your config look like? what do your full Elasticsearch logs show?